# switch to Javascript.click() function if element.click() function does not work

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How can i create a method that switch to **JavascriptExecutor.click()** function once if  **element.click()** or **action.moveToElement.click()** function  did not work .

Comment: Hello, can you provide us with the code you already wrote, that way we can help you determine what's wrong. Thank

Comment: Hi Jaay , I use this code to solve the click problems  which seems to me that it is too complicated , knowing that I always have false negatives following the elements that are not clicked,so i ask for a simplified code .Thanks

Comment: if (!findElements(locator).isEmpty()) {  
 try {           
 waitForElementPresent(locator);
 waitForElementvisible(locator);
 waitForElementToBeClickable(locator);
 if (_findElement(locator).isDisplayed()) { 
builder.moveToElement(_findElement(locator)).
click().build().perform();                     }
 catch (Exception e){

((JavascriptExecutor) 
 driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", _findElement(locator));
                 }
   }

Answer (score 0):

You can try to make the method like this:

```
     public void clickOnProvidedElement(WebElement element){
        try{
            element.click();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            try{
                actions.moveToElement(element).click();
            }
            catch (Exception a){
                JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
                js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
            }
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to know when the functions `element.click()` or `action.moveToElement.click()` is did not work. So I think it is the case by case situation. If the can-not-be-click-by-selenium is equal to wait-for-clickable-is-timeout, you can wait for the element is unclickable and use the `JavascriptExecutor.click()` when the timeout is shown.